# Enable Button if Inputs are not empty jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with two inputs, submit button is disabled by default. I want to enable the button if the inputs are not empty or when the browser auto fill the form. Is there a way of enabling the button when browser auto fill the form?. Currently I'm using setTimeout.

```
function notEmpty(){
if ($('#password').val() !== '' && $('#useremail').val() !== ''){
    button.prop('disabled',false);
}
}
setTimeout(function(){ notEmpty(); }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 3):

JS works better when you program it on event driven programming style.

You can use the trigger `oninput` to all the elements that you want to watch out for

```
$(function(){
    $('input').on('input',function(){
        if ($('#password').val() !== '' && $('#useremail').val() !== ''){
             $('button').prop('disabled',false);
        }
    }).trigger('input');
});
```

Comment: Works, but I have to click on the page before it is enabled.

Comment: You can trigger input programatically on `document.ready()` use `$('input').trigger('input')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#password, #useremail').change( function() {
    if ( $('#password').val()!="" && $('#useremail').val()!="" )
        button.prop('disabled',false);
});
```

Comment: Can you also explain the OP why and how your solution works?

Comment: well, jquery basically uses css syntax when it comes to selectors, so the most efficient way (i believe) is to bind the "change" event to both elements in the same declaration. the rest is pretty straightforward

Comment: true, but why did't you add this to your answer? :-)